# Oracle cursor's return type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to declare the following cursor:

```
CURSOR some_cursor RETURN oks_trips.trip_id % TYPE IS
    SELECT trip_id FROM oks_trips;
```

But i get an error:

```
Error(5,36): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
```

oks_trips.trip_id type is `NUMBER(3, 0)`, so i tried just NUMBER instead of `oks_tripd.trip_id % TYPE` but i still get the error.

I can't omit the `RETURN` statement because i declare cursor in package and oracle demands it there.

So the question is *WHY* can't i use `NUMBER` or `some_field % TYPE` in cursor's `RETURN` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/server.1111/e25789/srvrside.htm#sthref1038):

> You can declare a cursor explicitly within a procedure, function, or
>   package to facilitate record-oriented processing of Oracle Database
>   data. The PL/SQL engine can also declare cursors implicitly.

The important phrase there is 'record-oriented'. The [syntax for explicit cursor declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/explicit_cursor.htm) also clearly shows the return type has to be a `rowtype`, which it defines as:

> The data type of the row that the cursor returns.

You are asking it to return the datatype of a single column, not of a row/record. If you don't want to use an existing `%ROWTYPE` then Oracle provides the mechanism to declare a record type instead, as another answer has already shown.

You seem to be complaining that the documentation doesn't say that you can't use a scalar value as the return. It also doesn't say that you can't return a package, or a view, or a role. It doesn't need to exhaustively list everything you *cannot* do, since it clearly tells you exactly what you *can* do, which is to return a type that represents a row.

In your case that row type only needs to contain a single column, but there is still no reason you should be able to - or expect Oracle to - let you take a shortcut in that very limitd scenario. It doesn't seem unreasonable to provide a single consistent mechanism - it's not much of a hardship for you to declare the `record`, whereas them bulding, testing and maintaining a seperate path for this would be a considerable overhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for full and clear answer :)
The answer is really mentioned in docs, i don't know how did i overlook it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
   TYPE rec IS RECORD (trip_id oks_trips.trip_id % TYPE);
   CURSOR some_cursor RETURN rec;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mypackage AS
   CURSOR some_cursor RETURN rec IS
   SELECT trip_id FROM oks_trips;
END;
/
```

Comment: What about using a record around it?

Comment: Yes, i know this solution, my question is _WHY_ i can not use non-record type in `RETURN` clause.

Comment: Maybe Oracle was lazy to implement a separate syntact for this special case when the query returns only one column. :)

Comment: Well maybe :), but in that case i guess they would mention it in docs.

Comment: Actually I did not see it anywhere in my books with %TYPE, only with %ROWTYPE.

Comment: I didn't see it in the internet either. That's why i decided to ask the question here :)