# How does a %ROWTYPE return type wok for a cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have found the following pl/sql block in oracle official doc

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 RETURN departments%ROWTYPE IS  
 SELECT * FROM departments;
BEGIN
 NULL;
END;
```

I don't understand why do they use %ROWTYPE as the return type. Since a cursor is used to hold bulk amount of data(in this scenario) and %ROWTYPE is used to fecth single record or row how does a cursor return a %rowtype. Please provide a complete pl/sql block as above but with some statement that returning the above cursor.

Comment: Please check this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16135422/2244720)

Comment: Cursors do not contain data.  They are pointers to queries that can be executed to get the next row of data.  I don't understand what you mean by a "statement that return[s] the above cursor".  Are you asking for a function that returns a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Rowtype used to represent the typeof the row, eg. [structure of the returned row.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/rowtype_attribute.htm)

As Justin is correct, cursors do not contain data. [They are pointers to SQL statements](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:580621300346132183).

From the docs:The %ROWTYPE attribute provides a record type that represents a row in a database table. The record can store an entire row of data selected from the table or fetched from a cursor or cursor variable. Variables declared using %ROWTYPE are treated like those declared using a datatype name. You can use the %ROWTYPE attribute in variable declarations as a datatype specifier.